# Уменьшение времени при промахе по элементам, размещенным на PictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме размещен элемент Picturebox, на нем элементы (экземпляры класса MapObject), которые можно выделять мышью (через координаты в обработчике события MouseClick). На задачу отводится ограниченное время, которое уменьшается с помощью таймера Timer1. Как реализовать следующую логику: при промахе (клике мимо любого из элементов) время уменьшается (например, на 5 секунд)

```
public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        objects = new List<MapObject>();

        objects.Add(new MapObject()
        {
            Name = "Парусник",
            X = 180,
            Y = 34,
            Width = 27,
            Height = 37
        });

        objects.Add(new MapObject()
        {
            Name = "Пароход",
            X = 304,
            Y = 20,
            Width = 49,
            Height = 19
        });
        //добавление других объектов
    }
    List<MapObject> objects;
    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tk = --i;
        TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(tk);
        string label = span.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
        label1.Text = label.ToString();
        if (i <= 0)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            pictureBox2.Visible = true;

        }
    }
    int i;
    int tk;
    string c;
    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2.Visible = false;
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        i = 300;
        c = "5:00";

        label1.Text = c;
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }
    private void PictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int currentX = e.X;
        int currentY = e.Y;
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
        {
            if (currentX > (objects[i].X - objects[i].Width / 2) & currentX < (objects[i].X + objects[i].Width / 2)
            & currentY > (objects[i].Y - objects[i].Height / 2) & currentY < (objects[i].Y + objects[i].Height / 2))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ты нашел слово!");
            }

        }
    }
```

Для понимания логики работы привожу реализацию класса игрового элемента

```
class MapObject
{
    public string Name;

    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public int Width;
    public int Height;
}
```

Comment: Не ясно какое время вам нужно уменьшать. В timer.Interval? или то что в переменной string c; ? Или есть еще переменная tk. Сформулируйте задачу более четко.. Но я так понял не это Вас волнует?

Comment: Кстати ничто не мешает использовать для обхода List  оператор foreach ;)  да и currentX  и currentY только загрязняют код. Ну да ладно - вопрос не о стиле Вашего кода.

Comment: может должно быть вместо TimeSpan.FromMinutes(tk);   TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tk);    ? У вас там сколько - 5 минут или 300 минут?  А если все же 300 минут - то почему они тогда на 1 минуту каждую секунду уменьшаются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так, если я правильно понял что Вам требуется

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int currentX = e.X;
        int currentY = e.Y;
        //Переменная для проверки того что мы куда-то попали
        //По умолчанию предполагаем что мы никуда не попали
        bool FindSome = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
        {
            if (currentX > (objects[i].X - objects[i].Width / 2) & currentX < (objects[i].X + objects[i].Width / 2)
            & currentY > (objects[i].Y - objects[i].Height / 2) & currentY < (objects[i].Y + objects[i].Height / 2))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ты нашел слово: " + objects[i].Name);

                //Отмечаем, что у нас был клик по нужным координатам, куда-то попали
                FindSome = true;
            }
        }

        //Проверяем - был ли клик в нужные координаты
        if (!FindSome) TimeDec(); 

    }

    //Метод уменьшающий время - не знаю что у Вас в нем будет - может я угадал, может нет
    private void TimeDec()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Никуда не попали");
        //уменьшаем время. . . . я предположил что нужно уменьшать i 
        i-=5;
    }
```

Рекомендую также все-таки изменить обработчик таймера и сделать там все же секунды

```
    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tk = --i;
        TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tk);
        string label = span.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
        label3.Text = label.ToString();
        if (i <= 0)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            pictureBox2.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: пасибо огромное!

Comment: с уменьшением время все правильно!

Comment: зайдите в профиль и помогите пожалуйста с последним вопросом(про рейтинг)